# Access Resources on Runtime and get Strings

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I tried this to get the resource String in my Constants class

```
public static string OdVName = Resources.System.GetString(Resource.String.NewOrder);
```

And it throws me a not found error.

How i can access those Resources, said how can i get the Value without pointing to a View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried this to get the resource String in my Constants class

First of all you need object of Activity for getResource,as context you can get.

```
String str = context.getResources().getString(R.string.NewOrder);
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaa, it was a stupid question... Thank you that you replied anyway

Answer (score 0):

Follow Samir Magroliya... Still if you not get the String res. Just go for Menu --> Project --- > Clean project